# MySQL count multiple rows by where clause

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a group of queries like so:

```
SELECT count(users.id) AS `id` FROM users WHERE `vote` = 'cont6'
SELECT count(users.id) AS `id` FROM users WHERE `vote` = 'cont7'
SELECT count(users.id) AS `id` FROM users WHERE `vote` = 'cont8'
```

I was wondering how/if I could get this into a single query? So I get a result set similar to the following:

```
cont6 = 12
cont7 = 4
cont8 = 15
```

Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT vote, count(users.id) AS `id` FROM users GROUP BY vote
```

Comment: Yep - there was a timer stopping me from doing it straight away! All done!